# Discord js <@userid> doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, php, discord

I would like to know if its possible to tag user inside message.

For example:

```
msg.channel.send('display and tag user <@426369340> , thanks!').then(msg => {

})
```

And on bot message i get:

"display and tag user <@426369340> , thanks!"

I want:

"display and tag user @userName , thanks!"

Is it even possible ?

Comment: That is the right way to mention, check if the user is in the Server at all and bot have perms.

Comment: Okey i figure it out, im dumb but i paste my text inside " ``` ", that make text a code haha

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. Don't use `<@userID>`, use `<@!userID>`.